# Cassandra vs Hbase for storing the events count for every user

Tags: cassandra, hbase, cassandra-2.0

I was wondering whether we should use the Hbase or Cassandra for the following case :

1. I need the event tracking for every customer. Which will store one
   row for a customer on a daily basis and next day will create another
   row for the same customer. But that row may get updated quite
   frequently in a day for a customer.  Now, when there are quite
   frequent updates on a table.
2. In case of frequent updates data will get split in multiple
   SSTables. Which will lead to increase in latency while reading. What's the main purpose behind the counter in the cassandra?
3. Also, in case of hbase there is a problem of single point of
   failure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cassandra seems appropriate for your use case as it is very efficient at writes. It looks like the classic "time series" case: for each customer-day (=partition key), insert each event in the partition.
2. There are several strategies to improve update and read performance: insert new rows instead of updating existing ones, use leveled compaction instead of size tiered compaction, use caching... Counters are usually used to compute statistics like click count, page views... they can be unaccurate when failures occur and are bit less efficient than an upsert.
3. HBase is a master-slave, stores data in HDFS (less performance) and is more complex to setup (HDFS, Zookeeper) unless you already have an Hadoop distribution. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKkF9h1N-t0) might interest you (skip the beginning).

Comment: I am aware of setup of hbase as well as all the components which are required for them. but in terms of performance can you tell some points why cassandra would be better? Also, you are suggesting i should avoid updates on a row. And instead go for insert, right?

Comment: Write performance is better on Cassandra because: first Cassandra controls its files (less disk seeks, mechanical sympathy) whereas HBase has to cope with HDFS, then any node can write data and the master can not be a bottleneck, finally with CL ONE on write you won't wait for all replicas to acknowledge. In Cassandra, the write path is very straight forward. By tuning consistency on writes vs reads, you can favor one or the other from a performance point of view.

Comment: Updates are fine, they will require more compaction work, whereas Inserts will require more disk space: you can choose, but there is a trade off.

Comment: But we design our tables in such a way that i replaces the older rows with the new ones. So, still there would older rows exist in cassandra and would be using more space?

Comment: Older row state gets removed by compaction. The role of compaction is to merge rows scattered on different SSTables in a singe SSTable and also remove rows marked as deleted.

Comment: Is there any way like we have in hbase we can check in the hdfs whether older rows exist or not in cassandra?

Comment: I don't think so. Cassandra is not versionning row state. For row with fields A,B,C,D, you could have A,B,C,D on SSTable1, A',D' in SSTable2 and and A'',C'' in SST3. The final state being A'',B,C'',D'